# Simple jsonb_agg ORDER BY

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I'm just getting started with postgres and I have setup the simplest jsonb query. It runs, but doesn't order the json objects.

```
SELECT jsonb_agg(info ORDER BY info->'rating' DESC) FROM movies;
```

Where data looks like :

```
{
    "movie_card": {
        "cast": [
            { "actor": "Sam Worthington" },
            { "actor": "Zoe Saldana" },
            { "last": true, "actor": "Sigourney Weaver" }
        ],
        "name": "OKmovieee",
        "rating": 5,
        "writer": "James Bagel",
        "director": "James Bagel"
    }
}
```

Any idea whats wrong? This is the strangest thing, as I had the following query working before :

```
SELECT jsonb_agg(info) FROM movies ORDER BY rating DESC;
```

But since I've deleted the objects and recreated them, that query doesn't work (doesn't know what rating is).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SELECT jsonb_agg(info ORDER BY info->'movie_card'->'rating' DESC) FROM movies;`